# Default date format using generic views in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a generic.UpdateView but when I display the dates I got this format "2016-11-15 00:00:00"  When I want something like this dd/mm/yyyy.

```
class Updatebooking(generic.UpdateView):
        model = booking
        fields = ['name', 'mobile', 'email', 'date_out', 'date_in', 'indications'....]
```

I already change the settings.py to this

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-au'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True


DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y P'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
```

To display my html has a loop that is why I am not using something like this {{ date_in|date:"D d M Y" }}

```
<div class="widget-content" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2">{{ field.label_tag}}</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{field}}
                <span class="text-danger">{{field.errors}}</span>
                {% if field.help_text %}
                   <span class="text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
                {% endif %}
                </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Here's a good place to start: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

Comment: Please provide the model implementation (or at least the list of its fields). I have a gut feeling you have ```my_field = models.DateTimeField(...)``` instead of ```models.DateField(...)```. Got once birth dates displayed as "November 8, 1980, midnight".

Comment: where do you want to display `date_in` and where is the instance contains it ?

Comment: You could also set the default datetime format in settings.py `DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d'`